# How do I suppress or redirect (e.g. to a file) Testcontainer output in Testcontainers Scala with ZIO Test?

Tags: scala, testcontainers, zio, zio-test

I am using ZIO 2 and ZIO Test with plain testcontainers-scala.

The test looks like this:

```
object MongoRepositorySpec extends ZIOSpecDefault:

  object TestLayers:
    val mongoTestcontainer: ZLayer[Any, Throwable, MongoDBContainer] =
      ZLayer.scoped(
        ZIO.acquireRelease {
          ZIO
            .attempt(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:4.0.10"))
            .map(tag => MongoDBContainer.Def(tag))
            .map(_.createContainer())
            .tap(c => ZIO.attemptBlocking(c.start))
        }(container => ZIO.attemptBlocking(container.stop()).catchAll(t => ZIO.debug(s"Cannot stop container: $t")))
      )

    val mongoTestcontainerConfig: URLayer[MongoDBContainer, MongoConfig] = ZLayer.fromZIO(
      for container <- ZIO.service[MongoDBContainer]
      yield MongoConfig("localhost", container.mappedPort(27017), "", "", "test")
    )

  def spec = suite("MongoRepositorySpec")(
    test(s"Find GSM tower with cell id ${storedCellTowerGsm1.cellId}") {
      for
        _ <- MongoInserter.insert(storedCellTowerGsm1)
        cell <- MongoRepository.findBy(StoredCellType.Gsm, storedCellTowerGsm1.cellId, storedCellTowerGsm1.lac).some
      yield assertTrue(cell == storedCellTowerGsm1)
    }
  ).provide(
    mongoTestcontainer,
    mongoTestcontainerConfig,
    ZMongo.mongoDatabase,
    ZMongo.mongoClient,
    MongoRepository.live,
    MongoInserter.containerTests
  )
```

I want to suppress the container logs going to System out which interleave with the nice test reporting from ZIO test.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, I just needed to apply this https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/logging_config/.

and change this to suppress info and debug:

```
<root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```